# Formula to use as alternative date if cell is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to calculate employee service awards using a Date Joined column, and some staff have an alternative Date Joined due to a break in service.

**Example**

> Date Joined=C17
>   Alternative Date Joined=D17

Current formula I am using

```
=IF(C19="","",(YEARFRAC(C19,$D$3+1,1)-F19))
```

Can I use the `ISBLANK` formula to look at `D17` first, then, if blank, use `C17` in the above formula?

Comment: I think this could be better managed if you share some sample data with us,,the reason, If any employee has two join dates (since has service break) the which should be considered!! And how you are identifying the Service break ,, otherwise if simply you are struggling with trapping the blank cell the yes, `ISBLANK` can be used also. And what are in cells `D3` and in `F19` !!

Comment: If you have 2 Join Dates filled in `C17` and `D17` then the Date in `D17` is the latest and principally `D17` should consider with the formula,,, and if `C17` is blank (since is the earliest Date ) the no confusion check is `C17` is blank then `D17` !!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure I get what you're asking, but if you want to use D19 if C19 is empty, you can do

```
=YEARFRAC(IF(C19="",D19,C19),$D$3+1,1)-F19))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that worked, basically wanting to use an alternative date in the formula if one cell is blank.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. That will help others find it more easily.